# So when I deploy my code to CloudBees global.java won't run (Play Framework 2.1)

Tags: java, playframework, google-api, playframework-2.1, cloudbees

I'm just toying around with the google drive api (cloud storage) and figuring out how things work, I wrote some code in play framework where in global.java onStart access to the drive is gained and a test document is written to the drive. Locally this works fine but when I deploy my code to a new CloudBees app and visit the app I get this error in my log and I just can't figure out how to debug it:

```
Play server process ID is 7454
Oops, cannot start the server.
@6eonea90e: Cannot init the Global object
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:57)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:51)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:50)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$lzycompute(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:383)
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.global(Application.scala:66)
```

[Link to complete CloudBees log](http://pastebin.com/KWpykZ2m)

This is the code of Global.java:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import play.*;
import play.Logger;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private static String CLIENT_ID = "595172328396-l4kpto8ip9fpaea0k2987eeq8f42bged.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "EvTUvAodjGx2eW_d3k8oy8Fb";

    private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {    try{
        Logger.info("Application has started");

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(httpTransport).build()
                .setRefreshToken("1/MZ4GTNA_HMbOcKDSqp6ymSd11dlkgxoMXxfWwhwMJRg").setAccessToken("ya29.AHES6ZQk7NDC-OCba7_yANc_uqWPLwDLl95TlT_DXgkLqrr6qmyLRw");;




        //Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

        //Insert a file
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("New Document");
        body.setDescription("A test document");
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

        Logger.info("List of stuff: " + service.children().toString());

        Logger.info("File ID: " + file.getId());    }catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google access token is only good for 1 hour. It does not seem as if you are actually requesting an access token with your refresh token... Instead it seems like you are setting one that was already issued.

You need to request an access token be fetched (using the refresh token)

The "fun" is that once you use the refresh token to generate a new access token, the old ones are invalidated... Or at least that is the experience I have found...

Comment: Yeah I read that somewhere too, but now (10 hours after last test) I can still run my code without error locally, get access and create the test document.

Comment: Also, for later use as what I'm doing now is clearly wrong and why it works I dont know. Can you acquire a new access token with the refresh token in pure java? Because I could only find a javascript example.

Comment: Yes you can get it in pure java... Hmmm it may be you have the wrong "type" of client id... Ones designed for use from a web page via JavaScript are different (longer) than server used ones and may be tied to your IP

Comment: Wait, so for a desktop application (my case) the refresh token is tied to my IP? That would explain why my code stops working when I deploy it.